# Get a div inside a td with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the text inside the div in the class "atName".

I am looping though the table td's like this:

```js
var searchString = document.getElementById("search").value;
if (searchString !== "") {
    var cols = document.querySelectorAll('#theTable td'),
        colslen = cols.length,
        i = -1;

    while (++i < colslen) {
        if (cols[i].id.indexOf(searchString) > -1) {
            cols[i].style.opacity = "1"
        } else {
            Here i want to access the text inside the div
        }
```

Every td is set up like this:

```html
<td id="H" class="element nonmetal gasI">
    <div class="atN">1</div>
    <div class="atS gas"><a class="gas" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen" target="_blank">H</a></div>
    <div class="atName">Hydrogen</div>
    <div class="atW">1.00794</div>
</td>
```

I want the text inside the "atName" div.

Does anyone know how?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

Comment: `Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll(".atName"), function(element) {return element.textContent})`

Comment: Just a comment on your code, are you always going to have only one row in your table? Or are you trying to loop through all the cells in your table? I ask just because your variable name `cols` sounds like you might be thinking you're just looping over the columns of a single row

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same way you selected the `td`s:

```
cols[i].querySelector('.atName').textContent;
```

*btw. you should give different IDs to your `td`s or use classes because IDs should be unique*

---

UPDATE

To avoid any confusion, I'm already assuming we're looping the `td`s (from your code), and this line goes here:

```
while (++i < colslen) {
    if (cols[i].id.indexOf(searchString) > -1) {
        cols[i].style.opacity = "1"
    } else {
        var divText = cols[i].querySelector('.atName').textContent;  // <--- here
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Agree, this is going to be the best if you don't know which `<td>` you're looking for at the beginning. MDN docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector

Comment: @KenB, but you do, because you're in the loop. See OP's code and where this line goes.

Comment: yeah, I'm agreeing with you. I just mean that your approach with `Element.querySelector()` is better than, e.g., `document.getElementsByClassName()`, which was suggested in another answer (and updated since my comment to address this)

Comment: @KenB Ah yes, I explained in the comment why that one is not good. Sorry I misunderstood you.

Comment: When running this it gave me "Cannot read property 'textContent' of null". So i tried cheking for null, since some of the tds does not have the .atName div. But this caused the code not to be executed at all. It should eventaully come across one that does have this right? You can see the full source code here: http://madsanker.dk.linux101.unoeuro-server.com/ptable/pTable.php OBS you can log in using USERNAME: mads PASSWORD: 1234

Comment: I see, you can use this short code for disregarding null parents: `var atName = cols[i].querySelector('.atName') && cols[i].querySelector('.atName').textContent; ` The problem is that your selector also selects those blank cells (those that don't have an element inside), perhaps you could optimize it by giving a class name to all those that have an element.

Comment: @Shomz Why does this alert box not pop up? var atName = cols[i].querySelector('.atName') && cols[i].querySelector('.atName').textContent; alert(atName);

Comment: Works for me. Actually I'm using `console.log` because that's just too many alerts (one per table cell).

Comment: Oh. Forgot that i turned dialog boxes off ;). My bad. Thank you!

Comment: I did too! And was just reading an answer here on how to bring them back (reopen the tab). :) You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the object by class name :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('atName')
```

But this return you a list of object with this class.

So you can do in your while:

```
 while (++i < colslen) 
    {
        if (cols[i].id.indexOf(searchString) > -1) {
           cols[i].style.opacity = "1"
        } else {
           var text = cols[i].getElementsByClassName('atName')[0].textContent; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will return a node list of all the `.atName` elements, not just the one from inside the loop.

Comment: You're welcome. But you update won't work as well because you're still getting the node list (although only 1 element). You need `getElementsByClassName('atName')[0]` then.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help?

```
var searchString = "Hy";
if (searchString !== "") {
var cols = document.querySelectorAll('#theTable tr td .atName');
  for (var i=0;i<cols.length;i++)
  {
    if (cols[i].innerHTML.indexOf(searchString)>-1)
    {
        alert(cols[i].innerHTML);
    }
  }
}
```

What you're looking for is element.innerHTML but hopefully this selector trick will help you too.

Edit: element.textContent is different but you might desire to use it instead.

Comment: What about the part that changes the `td` opacity? :)